# PHP Error in validating SESSION variable

Tags: php, mysql

So I've made a login system here, it initiates a session, checks if the password is correct and then sets the session variables.

Here are a few things you might want to note:

- It successfully logs in
- There is no problem with the mysql connection
- All files are places correctly in folders
- There are no warnings or error messages
- The MYSQL Table structure is correct and there are no errors in database

Note: all functions I'm about to define are in the same file 'functions.php'

Over here we have the session function

```
include_once("global_config.php");
include_once("db_connect.php");
function sec_session_start()
{
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';
    $secure = SECURE;
    $httponly = true;
    if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE)
    {
        echo "Could not initiate a secure session";
        exit;
    }

    $cookieparams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieparams['lifetime'],$cookieparams['path'],$cookieparams['domain'],$secure,$httponly);
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

The global_config file define the mysql password, database, user and host and the db_connect file simply return the mysqli_connect to connect to the database.

And this over here is the login function

```
function login($user,$pass){
    sec_session_start();
    $link=linkit();
    if(empty($user) || empty($pass) || !isset($user) || !isset($pass)){
        echo "Error Code: 313, Please contact network administrator for more information";
        exit;
    }else{
        $usercheck = "SELECT `id`,`username`,`password`,`salt` FROM `".LOGINTABLE."` WHERE `username`=? LIMIT 1";
        if($stmt=$link->prepare($usercheck)){
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($id,$username,$realpassword,$salt);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();

            if(empty($realpassword)){
                echo 'Unrecognized Username, Please enter a valid username';
                exit;
            }else{
                if($realpassword===$pass){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',$pass);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    echo "Invalid Password!";
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The linkit() method is the one defined in db_connect.php which returns mysqli_connect. Also note that the script successfully makes it to setting the Session variable which means that it does return true.

NOW THE **PROBLEM** is this, when I'm checking for logged in status

```
function check_login()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
            isset($_SESSION['login_string']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = $_SESSIOOO['username'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];

        $pwd_check = "SELECT `password` FROM `".LOGINTABLE."` WHERE `user_id`=? LIMIT 1";
        if($stmt = linkit()->prepare($pwd_check))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($realpassword);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            $hashedpass = hash('sha512',$realpassword);
            if($login_string==$hashedpass){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
                return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

AND FINALLY, this is WHERE I process my login script. Also note that there are no errors in POST methods or anything else. They all work fine.

This is in a separate php file and **NOT** in the functions.php

```
<?php 
include_once '../includes/functions.php';
if(empty($_POST['loginuser']) || !isset($_POST['loginuser']) || !isset($_POST['id']) || empty($_POST['id']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    echo "Error Code: 412, Please contact network administrator for more information";
    exit;
}else{
    if($_POST['loginuser']==="true")
    {   
        $user = $_POST['id'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if(login($user,$pass)==true)
        {
            echo "Logged In!";
        }else
        {
            echo "Failed to login, check your username or password";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Additional Information** :

- The response I get is "Logged In"
- Session is successfully creaated

***PROBLEM: When I check for the login status, it returns false despite of having the session variables set.***

Comment: NOTE: The check_login() always RETURNS FALSE. THAT'S THE PROBLEM

Comment: Please make more clear **what the problem is**. You've dumped a lot of code with nary a mention of why you're dumping it all in the first place.

Comment: When I check for the login status, it returns false despite of having the session variables set.

Comment: Mention that at the appropriate point **in your question**, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In check_login you are hashing the password and then compare the unhashed password

```
function check_login()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) &&
            isset($_SESSION['login_string']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = $_SESSIOOO['username'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];

        $pwd_check = "SELECT `password` FROM `".LOGINTABLE."` WHERE `user_id`=? LIMIT 1";
        if($stmt = linkit()->prepare($pwd_check))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($realpassword);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            $hashedpass = hash('sha512',$realpassword);
            if($login_string==$hashedpass ){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
                return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even get to comparing the password. It fails because it the variables are not set.